# Sending file from SD card to android using ESP8266

Tags: android, esp8266

I came across this post

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10327506/android-arduino-bluetooth-data-transfer

where the author sends files from the arduino to android platform over bluetooth.

I am wondering, is this possible to achieve with the ESP8266 SoC?

I have no experience with it, but i am willing to buy and experiment, if it hads that functionality.

Comment: Will you be using an Arduino to transfer the data from the SD card to the ESP8266?  If so it should be possible.  If not it gets trickier - it might still be possible, but also ceases to be on topic here.

Comment: yeah, using the arduino of course